# Switch with number of cases being dependent on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, switch-statement, variadic-templates

I need an efficient way to turn a runtime-dynamic int in a range from 0 to N-1 into a template argument.

I.e., I want to create - logically speaking - a `switch` that switches a number between `0` and `N-1`. `N` is a template parameter, so the number of cases is fixed at compile time, but it is dependent on the template argument, so I cannot just use a normal switch.

The goal is to call a template lambda for each case where the switched-upon number is passed to the lambda as a template argument. I.e., I want to go from a dynamic number to a static template argument. So in pseudo-code, I want to reach something like this:

```
template<size_t N, typename Lambda>
auto switchOverN(int n, Lambda lambda) {
   assert(n < N && n >= 0);
   switch (n) {
      case 0: return lambda<0>();
      case 1: return lambda<1>();
      ...
      case N-1: return lambda<n-1>();
   }
}
```

The solution should only use templates, no macros. Of course I cannot use a normal `switch` due to the varying number of cases.

How can I achieve this? Here is what I have so far.

I use a combination of `std::variant`, `std::make_index_sequence`, & `std::integral_constant` to give me a variant of all integral constants between 0 and N-1:

```
template<size_t I>
struct IndexVariantHelper {
   template<std::size_t... I>
   std::variant<std::integral_constant<int, I>...> toVariant(std::index_sequence<I...>) { return {}; }

   typename type = decltype(toVariant(std::make_index_sequence<I>()));
}
```

So now I can use `IndexVariantHelper<N>::type` to get a variant of index sequences and I can use `std::visit` to perform the switch. So I am *almost* done...:

```
template<size_t N, typename Lambda>
auto switchOverN(int n, Lambda lambda) {
   typename IndexVariantHelper<N>::type switcher = ... // Here's the missing part
   return std::visit([&]<typename Idx>(const Idx&) {
      constexpr size_t i = Idx::value;
      return lambda<i>();
   }, switcher);
```

So the switching can now be done, nice! And the good news is that the resulting code is blazingly efficient. The compiler can look through all the templates and indeed generate very efficient code for the switch. It can even constant fold it - depending on the lambda of course. Here is an example: https://godbolt.org/z/v31sdKWv1

My only remaining problem is how to get the dynamic input `n` into the variant. I am running out of ideas here.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered looking at an `initializer_list`? It works much like a vector or an array (but is immutable) and you could access your lambda using the index.

Comment: What is the original and underlying problem you're trying to solve? How would such a `switch` statement solve that problem? Perhaps there are other ways to solve that original and underlying problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need to have a number from 0 to N-1 available as a template parameter, as I need to be able to choose between N template arguments. And I need this transition from dynamic integer to static template argument to be fairly efficient, as this will be in hot-ish code. So if possible, I want to avoid an if-cascade. The method should be O(1) complexity.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to solve the X/Y problem here, but I really need basically what I wrote: A way to turn a dynamic integer into a template argument with efficient code. I have edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Given that template parameters must be evaluated at compile time, but you're trying to map values obtained (read? calculated?) at run time, the mapping must happen at run time.   The normal ways are (1)  if you must use a templated function with template parameter, then an `if`-`else` cascade  (2)  do away with the templated function entirely, and have the function accept a normal argument (which the caller can obtain at runtime).   You might want to consider a `constexpr` function if you can meet the conditions (e.g. some calls passing values known at compile time).

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_with_indexni_f does basically the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array of functor does that job

```
template <std::size_t N>
auto toIntegralConstantVariant(std::size_t n)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array{
            +[]() -> std::variant<std::integral_constant<size_t, Is>...>{
                return std::integral_constant<size_t, Is>{};
            }...
        }[n]();
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e63M18b5q)

Comment: I ended up with this solution, as it doesn't need any function pointers and allows me to transform the integer into a std::variant<std::integral_constant..> on a less hot part of the code path and then re-use the pre-baked std::variant for a dispatch with std::visit. It also answers my initial request best, as it shows how to use the variant + integral constant approach I sketched instead of switching to something completely different (even though I am open to switching in case there is a better alternative, but I don't think the other alternatives are better than this one).

Answer (score 3):

`std::index_sequence`, function pointers, and a few other things come to the rescue:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N, typename Lambda>
auto switchOverN(std::size_t n, Lambda&& lambda) {
    // 1. Figure out the return type (important for function pointers)
    //    If not every specialization of the call operator has the same return type,
    //    you might need to take the std::common_type of all, or fail an assertion, etc.
    using ReturnType = decltype(std::forward<Lambda>(lambda).template operator()<0>());

    // 2. create an array of function pointers at compile-time
    //    note: static constexpr in constexpr functions is possible since C++23, if needed
    static constexpr auto functions = []<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::array<ReturnType(*)(Lambda&&), N>{
            // Since C++17, capture-less lambdas can be turned into function pointers.
            // Each function pointer at functions[I] invokes lambda<I>, so that
            // we just have to look up the function pointer by index.
            +[](Lambda&& lambda) -> ReturnType {
                return std::forward<Lambda>(lambda).template operator()<I>();
            }...
        };
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    
    // 3. invoke the right function pointer
    return functions[n](std::forward<Lambda>(lambda));
}

int main() {
    switchOverN<3>(1, []<std::size_t I> {
        std::cout << I << '\n';
    });
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bbr5h5EYf)*

This solution keeps everything in one function and has minimal overhead. We can tell that the overhead is very low:

```cpp
void take(std::size_t i);

void foo(std::size_t i) {
    switchOverN<4>(i, []<std::size_t I> {
        take(I);
    });
}
```

This compiles to (GCC 14, `-O2`):

```
foo(unsigned long):
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     rax, rdi
        lea     rdi, [rsp+15]
        call    [QWORD PTR ...::functions[0+rax*8]]
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

Besides some stack alignment boilerplate, the compiler just loads an address from a table and makes a dynamic call.
Each of the functions that may be jumped is a two-liner:

```
        mov     edi, 3
        jmp     take(unsigned long)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with classic unrolling a loop:

```
auto lambda = []<int NN>() { std::cout << "Lambda called for instance " << NN << std::endl; };

    template < int N >
void Call_Impl( int n )
{
    if ( N == n )  
    {    
        lambda.template operator()<N>();
    }
    else 
    {    
        if  constexpr ( N!= 1 )
        {
            Call_Impl<N-1>(n);
        }    
    }    
}


    template < int MAX_N>
void Call(int n)
{
    Call_Impl<MAX_N>(n);
};

int main()
{
    Call<10>(4);
}
```